# Identity of return value of getOwnPropertyDescriptor handler for Javascript Proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some very simple code:

```js
var out = null

const handler = {
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
    out = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop)
    return out
  }
}

const obj = new Proxy({foo: "bar"}, handler)
const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'foo')
console.log(desc)
console.log(out)
console.log(desc == out)
```

When run under nodejs, v 18.03, this will result in `false`, which makes no sense to me: Usually, an object will retain identity on either side of a return. So two questions:

- Does anyone know why? (Is this a bug in node? A weird implementation detail? Working as intended?)
- Is there anywhere else where I have to watch out for an object not being the same after being returned?

Comment: "*Does anyone know why?*" counter question - why would you expect *any* specific result here?

Comment: It's also `false` when I run it in any browser. `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` returns a new object every call.

Comment: I would generally expect that an object before returning is the same as an object after returning. `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` should return a new object every time, but I would think that the object on the start-side of the return should be the same object on the end-side of the return?